# Python nested list comprehension (accessing nested elements)

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, nested, list-comprehension

I'm having trouble understanding the syntax here.

```
matrix_a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
matrix_b = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

[a for a, b in matrix_a]
```

output: `[1, 3, 5]`

```
[a for b, a in matrix_a]
```

output: `[2, 4, 6]`

I understand a little about how list-comprehensions work, but I don't understand the syntax when accessing certain elements within a nested list.

I just can't wrap my head around this syntax. How is this syntax working? What does the comma represent? What does `a for a` mean? Can you explain whats going on under the hood? And finally how would you do this with `matrix_b`

Comment: The question listed as a duplicate is about nested list comprehensions, this question is not about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you convert it to a for loop it might be easier to see..?

```
res = []
for item in matrix_a:
    a, b = item   # a = item[0]; b = item[1]
    res.append(a)
```

you're basically unpacking the individual items in the list and picking one of them.

Comment: How would this look as a list-comprehension for matrix_b?

Comment: the case of matrix_b is the same, but you will unpack three vars
`[a for a,b,c in matrix_b]`

Comment: Ok, I see it now. I was reading it as two separate statements `a for a,` and `b in matrix_a`. Wow thanks for clarifying that :D You guys are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mistaken in writing output here
[a for a, b in matrix_a] returns [1 2 4] which is logical , returning first element of each nested list item

see the [image: Output]screenshot

Comment: You could have copied the text instead of using an image.  Also, this doesn't seem like an _answer_ ..?

Answer (score 0):

just understand in this way:

```
[a for b, a in matrix_a]  #as
[a for [a, b] in matrix_a] #or
[a for (a, b) in matrix_a]
#matrix_a has elements as list of length 2 each
#so your list comprehenssion says, give me a output list -- having first element'a' from each element of matrix_a(whose each element represented as [a,b] type, with comma, becomes tuple (a,b)),
# then from [b,a] give me a, that is 2nd element
# and it will fail if you apply same on matrix_b, cause each element of matrix_b is not of type [a,b] i:e of length 2
# you will get "ValueError: too many values to unpack"
```

Let me know if anything is not clear. Thanks.